# How to make the query work in linux server?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have an database in PostgreSQL called "myDatabase" which has hundreds of schema and which is installed in Linux server. I am using this DB for an SAAS application. Which has multiple schema users. I want to update a column value in a table for selected schema

There is a particular column 'Percentage' in a table called 'sales' which i want to update the column value for all the existing users(Schema). So i have written a script to update the values in all schemas, this script is working in windows server but when i trying to execute this script in linux server, it shows an error

`enter code here`The below script i have written,

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _schema text;

BEGIN

FOR _schema IN
    SELECT quote_ident(nspname)  -- prevent SQL injection
    FROM   pg_namespace n
    WHERE  nspname !~~ 'pg_%' and nspname between 'schema1' and 'schema50'
    AND    nspname <>  'information_schema'
LOOP
   EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL search_path = ' || _schema;
   UPDATE  sales SET  sales.Percentage = 15;
END LOOP;

END
$do$
```

The above script is working in windows server but it is not working linux server. The error is given below

ERROR:  column "sales" of relation "sales" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE  sales SET  sales.Percentage = 5
                              ^
QUERY:  UPDATE  sales SET  sales.Percentage = 5
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Do not specify table name before the column name in the update:

```
UPDATE  sales SET  Percentage = 15
```

Here is the example that demonstrates this:

```
laika=# create table a (i integer);
CREATE TABLE
laika=# update a set a.i = 1;
ERROR:  column "a" of relation "a" does not exist
LINE 1: update a set a.i = 1;
                     ^
laika=# update a set i = 1;
UPDATE 0
```